# CodeIgniter 4: 'BadMethodCallException' trying to insert or update data

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

**UPDATE: I found the problem a couple days ago in the parent controller, nothing about the code I've posted.**

I've created a simple CodeIgniter 4 model and I don't have any clue about what's wrong. By default, this kind of models includes basic CRUD methods so you don't need to declare them in it.

When I use some of those basic methods like **find()**, **findAll()** or even **delete()** it works fine, but when I try to use **insert()** or **update()** CodeIgniter throws this exception:

> BadMethodCallException
>
> Call to undefined method App\Models\LocalesModel::update

The controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use App\Models\LocalesModel;

class AdminLocales extends Controller
{
    protected $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new LocalesModel();
    }

    /*
     * Doesn't work!
     */

    public function insertAction()
    {
        $data = $this->request->getPost();

        if ($this->model->insert($data) === false) {
            // display error...
        }
    }

    /*
     * Doesn't work!
     */

    public function updateAction($id)
    {
        $data = $this->request->getPost();

        if ($this->model->update($id, $data) === false) {
            // display error...
        }
    }

    /*
     * Works fine!
     */

    public function deleteAction($id)
    {
        if ($this->model->delete($id) === false) {
            // display error...
        }
    }
}
```

The model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class LocalesModel extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'locales';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $useAutoIncrement = true;
    
    protected $returnType     = 'array';
    protected $useSoftDeletes = false;
    
    protected $allowedFields = ['title', 'code', 'enabled'];
    
    protected $useTimestamps = true;
    protected $createdField  = 'created_at';
    protected $updatedField  = 'updated_at';
    protected $deletedField  = 'deleted_at';
    
    protected $validationRules    = [
        'title'   => 'required',
        'code'    => 'required',
        'enabled' => 'in_list[Y,N]'
    ];
    protected $validationMessages = [];
    protected $skipValidation     = false;
}
```

(I've checked the $data array content and it's ok, only includes the $allowedFields and the values are fine)

I've used pretty similar codes in the past without any problem. Anyone know what might be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see a constructor in your model nor the call to the parent model's constructor that would be inside it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but this kind of CI models doesn't require a constructor. I found the problem a couple days ago in the parent controller, nothing about the code I post before.

Comment: Can you share the output of $data